# How to JavaScript a button to alert what other buttons are currently active?

Tags: javascript, html, button, show

I'm very inexperienced at JavaScript so please forgive my terrible description! (Also it has to be JavaScript not jQuery as its going to work on a closed system (no Internet access).

So I want the last PLAY button clicked by the user to give an alert of what other buttons are currently active by reporting back their IDs.

All the buttons are the same class `<btnpluse>` but they all have unique ids. There are 4 groups of these buttons and only one button in a group can be active at one time. There are four functions that make this happen.

Once the user has selected one button from each group I would like the PLAY button to spit out an alert (and print it in the code) saying which on the active buttons have been selected so that eventually this can let me know what the user wants to 'play'

I've figured out how to get the id for a button when you press it, but can't seem to find code for a button that reports another buttons id if it has a function which has a CSS attached to it!

So here is my code so far.

```js
function char(obj){

    if (document.querySelector(".activeC")) 
 {
        document.querySelector(".activeC").className = document.querySelector(".activeC").className.replace(" activeC",""); 
    }
    obj.className = obj.className + " activeC";
}
function rate(obj){

    if (document.querySelector(".activeR")) 
 {
        document.querySelector(".activeR").className = document.querySelector(".activeR").className.replace(" activeR",""); 
    }
    obj.className = obj.className + " activeR";
}
function sym(obj){

    if (document.querySelector(".activeS")) 
 {
        document.querySelector(".activeS").className = document.querySelector(".activeS").className.replace(" activeS",""); 
    }
    obj.className = obj.className + " activeS";

}
function rhy(obj){
  
    if (document.querySelector(".activeRH")) 
 {
        document.querySelector(".activeRH").className = document.querySelector(".activeRH").className.replace(" activeRH",""); 
    }
    obj.className = obj.className + " activeRH";
}

function playstop(obj, id) {

document.getElementById("playstop");

  var btnOn = document.getElementById('playstop');
 btnOn.classList.toggle('orange');
 if (btnOn.innerHTML === "PLAY") {
    btnOn.innerHTML = "STOP";
  } else {
    btnOn.innerHTML = "PLAY";
  }
 var showAlert = document.getElementById('playstop');
 if(document.getElementsByClassName + "activeRH")
  showAlert = (id);
 alert(this.id);
}
```

```css
h1 {
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #ec6607;
 height: 5px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #ec6607;
 height: 5px; 
}
h3{
 font-size:14px;
 color: #fca600;
 padding-left: 10px;
 height: 5px;
 }
.Pulse-Char{
 width: 100%;
 height: 505px;
 display: block;
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
.Pulse-CharBG{
    height: 26%;
 width:96%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
 outline: auto;
 outline-color: #c4c4c4;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 1px #c4c4c4;
}
.Pulse-CharBG2{
    height: 21.3%;
 width:96%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
 outline: auto;
 outline-color: #c4c4c4;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 1px #c4c4c4;
}
.Pulse-CharBG3{
    height: 20.3%;
 width:96%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
 outline: auto;
 outline-color: #c4c4c4;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 1px #c4c4c4;
}
.Pulse-CharBG4{
    height: 10.3%;
    width: 96%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    outline: auto;
    outline-color: #c4c4c4;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 1px #c4c4c4;
}
.col{
    width: 31.3%;
 display: block;
    float: left;
 padding-left: 2%;
 padding-top: 1%;
 }
.colrate{
    width: 22%;
 display: inline-block;
    float: left;
 padding-left: 3%;
 }
.pulse-panel .Pulse-Char .PlayBtnArea {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
 }
.colplay{
    width: 96%;
 display: inline-block;
    float: left;
 padding-left: 3%;
 }
btnpulse{
    width: 80%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    color: #ec6607;
    margin: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: medium solid #EC6607;
 cursor: pointer;
}
btnplaystop{
    width: 80%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    color: #ec6607;
    margin: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: medium solid #EC6607;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
btnpulse.activeC { 
 background-color: #ec6607 !important; 
 color:antiquewhite;
}
btnpulse.activeRH { 
 background-color: #ec6607 !important; 
 color:antiquewhite;
}
btnpulse.activeR { 
 background-color: #ec6607 !important; 
 color:antiquewhite;
}
btnpulse.activeS { 
 background-color: #ec6607 !important; 
 color:antiquewhite;
}
btnplaystop.orange{
 background-color: #ec6607 !important; 
 color:antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div class="Pulse-Char">
    <div class="Pulse-CharBG">
        <h3>Pulse Character</h3>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnPulNor" onClick = "char(this)">Normal</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnPulWeak" onClick = "char(this)">Weak</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnPulSlow" onClick = "char(this)">Slow rising</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnPulBou" onClick = "char(this)">Bounding</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnPulBis" onClick = "char(this)">Bisferens</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnPulAlt" onClick = "char(this)">Alternans</btnpulse></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Pulse-CharBG2">
        <h3>Rhythm</h3>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnRhyReg" onClick = "rhy(this)">Regular</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnRhyRegIrr" onClick = "rhy(this)">Regularly Irregular</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnRhyIrrIrr" onClick = "rhy(this)">Irregularly Irregular</btnpulse></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Pulse-CharBG3">
        <h3>Rate</h3>
        <div class="colrate"><btnpulse id = "btnRate40" onClick = "rate(this)">40</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="colrate"><btnpulse id = "btnRate70" onClick = "rate(this)">70</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="colrate"><btnpulse id = "btnRate120" onClick = "rate(this)">120</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="colrate"><btnpulse id = "btnRate180" onClick = "rate(this)">180</btnpulse></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Pulse-CharBG2">
        <h3>Symmetry</h3>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnSymNor" onClick = "sym(this)">Normal</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnSymRR" onClick = "sym(this)">Radio-radial delay</btnpulse></div>
        <div class="col"><btnpulse id = "btnSymRF" onClick = "sym(this)">Radio-femoral delay</btnpulse></div>
    </div>
    <div class="PlayBtnArea">
        <div class="colplay"><btnplaystop id = "playstop" onClick = "playstop()">PLAY</btnplaystop></div>
    </div>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just query for elements that have the `activeXX` class (differing XX), and get their `id` properties.

```
let ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".activeC, .activeRH, .activeR, .activeS"), btn => btn.id);
```

`ids` is an array. If you `alert(ids)`, you will see a comma separated list of `id` property values.

Remark: the following lines in your code do not make sense to me:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName + "activeRH")
    showAlert = (id);
```

`document.getElementsByClassName` is a function, and then you perform a string addition to that function object, concatenating "activeRH". That gives a string value, which you then convert to a boolean since it is an `if` expression. That will always be `true`, since the string is not empty. I have no clue what you were trying to do there.

Also the parentheses around `id` are not doing anything. Moreover, `obj` and `id` are undefined, as `playstop` is called without arguments.

Comment: Fantastic - it worked like a dream! Thank you so much! :D Yes sorry about that other random code at the bottom of the js.. it was a left over from all the random stuff i tried. I did look up arrays but I just didn't know how to implement them.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!